# How to handle concurrent Maven builds on Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I use Jenkins a lot and lots of different jobs run on the cluster. Every now and then a job fails with some obscure error and I've been able to debug this to the fact that job A is using an artifact X and a job B has just downloaded or a built a fresh version of it (with maven).

The job A fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError or something else with ZIP file being corrupt or segfault from some ZIP implementation that Java is using.

So the obvious solution would to use private local maven repository for the jobs but that is quite disk and internet expensive solution. This would mean each job's maven would download the whole internet.

For some cases a eager loading of class files from the JAR file that corrupts often helps us limit the damage but don't want to do that for everything.

Any other solutions? Some sort of improved locking for the repository?

Comment: Have you explored the 'lock build while upstream/downstream project is building' options?

Comment: Yes, using that but this can happen almost with almost any dependency so if I use the plugin for everything I can have only one job with maven to run at a time :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, looks like maven doesn't like concurrent access to a single local repository (there is an [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2802) opened recently, just 7 years ago). Creating repo for each job could be quite massive. However, there is a variable `$EXECUTOR_NUMBER`, so maybe you could use it to create maven local repo per each Jenkins executor.

Comment: Better use the configuration option in Jenkins to have a repository per Job or executor.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, good point. The executor-dependent repo location could be configured by jenkins global configuration.

Comment: @kan the issue is currently closed without actually be fixed, using the `$EXECUTOR_NUMBER` is not a really solution for a large team which they are working on same component, and currently I have this issue with Jenkins Multibranch pipeline. Is there any other way to avoid this issue?

Comment: @khmarbaise using _repo per project_ is not really disk usage friendly, especially if you are using a multibranch. I am not sure even this library helps [Concurrent Safe Local Repository Access](http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html) as it has open issue and is not maintained for years. this is pretty annoying issue,

Comment: Are we really discussing about disk space in 2021? I'm maintaining a lot of multi branch projects (50+branches; cloned repo sizes from 500 MiB upto serveral GiB)..apart from that if it's really an issue which bothers you can can of course offer a patch to fix the issue because the Apache Maven project is an open source project... furthermore you should read the [release notes of Maven 3.8.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12316922&version=12349965).  Also see https://blogs.apache.org/maven/

Comment: @MK83 Not sure why it's not a solution? I doubt you have too many executors in a single Jenkins instance. As far as I remember, executors are allocated across all jobs, no matter what type of pipeline it is.

Comment: @khmarbaise depends on environment! for some is still matter, but in general agree with you. now if I consider to have a dedicated repo for each build (also with Multibranch) but for the first time downloading artifacts takes time. it seems I have to choose one of these suggestions. anyway thanks!

Comment: @MK83 You don't need dedicated maven repo for each build. You need repo per each executor. Number of executors is fixed and defined by server hardware - available mem and cpu cores. Usually it's not more than 10.

Comment: @kan thanks, sure not each build, I wanted to say for each branch or pull request. I will try to follow what you mentioned